# How to determine from a remote host which local IP sent a request

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

Suppose that I have 1 network of many computers connected to the Internet through a Router Wifi Dlink or a NAT device. On the other end a computer connected directly to the internet which provides some services to the connected clients. As soon one of the computer of the local network connects to the directly connected computer on the other end through the internet I want to determine on the directly connected computer through a Socket or in other ways which of the computer of the local network sent the request. Is this possible ?

I for example know that some Internet Service Providers limit the number of possible computers connected to the Internet even if the computer is located behind a router. It means that in such ways the Internet Service Providers could determine which computer behind the router has performed a connection request..and limits the connection to all the others. How to explain this ?

Comment: you can't do this without the client sending this information to the server... what the ISPs do is something entirely different - since you use some modem/router they get that information from the modem/router...

Comment: ok..and how can I get this from the modem/router too ?

Comment: you can't - usually the used protocol for this communication is secured (mechanisms vary depeding on the ISP and remote modem/router). What is the goal exactly ?

Comment: The goal? I have client software from third party which don't sends by default information to the server except the data. Is there a way to set the router so that every client is connected directly to the internet and that the clients aren't behind the NAT ? Or should I simply remove the Router to achieve this ?

Comment: yes - you can configure the router/modem to achieve that although the options and outcome very much depend on your specific router/modem and ISP...

Comment: Any suggestion about how to configure the router so that the server can distingue between the different client from a LAN ? I thought to open on the server 1 port for each client and to force each client to connect to his port. But if clients are 2000 ..this may be rude and resource consuming.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to find this directly from the objects. What I would recommend if you need to know the local IP Address of the sending system, is have the client send the information in to the server as the first thing it does after it connects to the server. So, after accepting the connection the server should expect a set of data that will contain the local IP information send by the client that just connected.